# Are more opcodes represented using the R instruction format?

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, instruction-set

[image]

If the opcode for R-format instruction can be all 0s and the six least significant bits can be used instead, does this mean that more opcodes can be represented with the R-format? Since the other instruction formats do not have the funct instruction?

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. If you fix `OP` at zero then you basically changed `funct` into `OP` and both are 6 bits so it's the same number of instructions. If you consider non-zero `OP`, then yes, more instructions can be encoded with R format.

Comment: @Jester Oh, does that mean that both the `OP` and `funct` instruction can be used to represent a single opcode?

Comment: Looking at the actual instruction set it seems all R format have `OP=0`. But theoretically you could have other values too.